# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java

I have an issue I believe it may be a simple fix but I am currently stuck.

I have tried looking around but couldn't find anything helpful.

This is my error:  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

[image: Code error picture here aswell]

This is my code:

```
} else if (token.equals("character-rights")) {
        player.getRights().ordinal() = Integer.parseInt(token2);


    public enum PlayerRights {

    PLAYER(true, true, true, true, false, 60),
    MODERATOR(true, true, true, true, false, 0),
    ADMINISTRATOR(false, false, false, false, false, 0),
    DEVELOPER(true, true, true, true, true, 0),
    DONATOR(true, true, true, true, true, 10);

    private boolean canTrade, canDuel, canPk, canSell, debugMode;
    private int yellTimer;

    private PlayerRights(boolean canTrade, boolean canDuel, boolean canPk, boolean canSell, boolean debugMode, int yellTimer) {
        this.canTrade = canTrade;
        this.canDuel = canDuel;
        this.canPk = canPk;
        this.canSell = canSell;
        this.debugMode = debugMode;
        this.yellTimer = yellTimer;
    }

    private static final ImmutableSet<PlayerRights> STAFF = Sets.immutableEnumSet(ADMINISTRATOR, DEVELOPER);
    private static final ImmutableSet<PlayerRights> MEMBERS = Sets.immutableEnumSet(MODERATOR, ADMINISTRATOR, DEVELOPER, DONATOR);
    private static final ImmutableSet<PlayerRights> NORMAL = Sets.immutableEnumSet(PLAYER, DONATOR);

    public boolean isStaff() {
        return STAFF.contains(this);
    }

    public boolean isMember() {
        return MEMBERS.contains(this);
    }

    public boolean isPlayer() {
        return NORMAL.contains(this);
    }

    public boolean canTrade() {
        return canTrade;
    }

    public boolean canDebug() {
        return debugMode;
    }

    public boolean canSell() {
        return canSell;
    }

    public boolean canDuel() {
        return canDuel;
    }

    public boolean canPk() {
        return canPk;
    }

    public int getYellTimer() {
        return yellTimer;
    }

}
```

and

```
public PlayerRights playerRights;

public PlayerRights getRights() {
    return playerRights;
}
```

The top code is where the error takes place. I would really appreciated some help, would make my day.

Comment: `player.getRights().ordinal()` ... this is not a variable and can't appear on the LHS of an assignment.  Your IDE is pointing this out for you.

Comment: What do you expect `player.getRights().ordinal() = Integer.parseInt(token2);` to actually do?  To what are you attempting to assign the result of `Integer.parseInt(token2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are immutable. You need to reassign a new enum value instead of writing things like

```
myEnum.ordinal() = 0;
```

You have to write a switch statement to check what `Integer.parseInt(token2)` is, and use the `setRights` method.

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(token2)) {
    case 0:
        player.setRights(PlayerRights.PLAYER);
        break;
    case 1:
        player.setRights(PlayerRights.MODERATOR);
        break;
    case 2:
        player.setRights(PlayerRights.ADMINISTRATOR);
        break;
    case 3:
        player.setRights(PlayerRights.DEVELOPER);
        break;
    case 4:
        player.setRights(PlayerRights.DONATOR);
        break;
}
```

If your `player` class does not have a `setRights` method, you should probably add one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following method to the class (Player?) that contains **public PlayerRights getRights()** :

```
public void setRights(PlayerRights rights) {
  this.playerRights = rights;
}
```

Now, call this setter method in the line you have in the screen shot:

```
player.setRights(PlayerRights.values()[Integer.parseInt(token2)];
```

Be ready to catch an array-out-of-bounds exception for wrong input.